# Transferring Data from OLTP to OLAP databases

Tags: olap

Systems that have both OLTP and OLAP databases periodically move data from the OLTP database to the OLAP database, so that reports can be generated based on the OLAP database.

What's the official term for this process and is there an overview of this process online?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is mostly referred as ETL process (extraction, transformation, and load).

Here are a link of MSDN article on [Transforming OLTP Data to OLAP Data Warehouses](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa933151.aspx). It is an old article but the same concept applied.

Answer (score 4):

Microsoft SQL Server Analysis Services uses the term ["cube processing"](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa216366%28v=SQL.80%29.aspx).

Kimball seems to usually use the term ["dimensional model loading"](http://www.kimballgroup.com/1997/08/02/a-dimensional-modeling-manifesto/).

Accordingly, I use the term "ETL" to refer to copying data from the OLTP systems into the staging database (or for copying data from one OLTP database to another) and the term "cube processing" to refer to copying data from the staging database into the OLAP databases.